# How to invoke a Swift class in a Objective-C file imported in a Swift project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

[It's not a dup of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823220/how-to-import-swift-file-into-objective-c-file-in-a-swift-project)
I imported Objective-C files into a Swift project. But there is a login controller that has a callback invoking AppDelegate.
But the AppDelegate is a Swift file.
According to the [Apple's guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html), I added an `ExampleProject-Swift.h` header file then imported this header file in the login controller.
But it doesn't seem to be the right way. 
[image]

And in the `AppDelegate.swift` file
[image]

The code below is what I did in the `ExampleProject-Swfit.h` header.

```
#ifndef ExampleProject_swift_h
#define ExampleProject_swift_h

#import "AppDelegate.swift"
#endif /* ExampleProject_swift_h */
```

BTW, to use an Objective-C file, I already created an `ExampleProject-Bridging-Header.h`.
I don't know what's really going on here, anyone has any idea about how to solve this problem?
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-swift-classes-in-objective-c/ try checking this or https://ios.james.ooo/using-swift-in-objective-c-projects-f7e7a09f8be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ExampleProject_Swift.h file is autogenerated by the compiler, so you shouldn't be adding your own.

Also, in the header file you created, you imported a Swift source file as if it was an Objective C header file, and the compiler isn't going to understand that. That is why you're getting all of those strange errors in the LoginViewController implementation file.

Comment: This works. Thank you man. But I got another problem. I have some global macros, to use them in swiftI, I made some global `let` variables in a swift file, but the Objective-C file can't find those variables. What else should I do?  In addition, in the old Objective-C project, I made a `PreFixHeader.pch` to import a file containing those macros.

Comment: The Swift compiler only handles very simple macros. If you want your Swift variables to be visible to Objective C, you'll need to make them public.

Comment: Yeah, I've made it. The default internal access level is working. The automatically created Swift header, according to the Apple's document, will contain those marked by `internal ` modifier if there is an Objective-C bridging header. Thanks for you help, I was really confused about all this migration stuff.